# Create Failed Style to my custom type (WPF)

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

Here i got problem with applying style to my custom type. In below code. I made a one extended listview type called as "MyListView" and it's referred from Inventory.Interface.
For this created on style. It's showing while debug time perfectly. but while run time it's showing error like this

**'Failed to create a 'Type' from the text 'man:MyListView'.' Line number '8' and line position '12'.**

Why it is coming, whats wrong with this.

```
<ResourceDictionary 
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:src="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:man="clr-namespace:Inventory.Interface"
                >
<Style TargetType="{x:Type man:MyListView}">
     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFDFDFE2"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#faf2f2"/>
      </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Is your type `MyListView` present in some other assembly? If so, specify the assembly. e.g.`xmlns:man="clr-namespace:Inventory.Interface;assembly=MyOtherAssembly"`. And what do you mean by 'showing while debug time perfectly. but while run time...'? Do you mean compile time instead of debug time?

Comment: post the solution (that worked for you) as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ResourceDictionary 
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:src="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:man="clr-namespace:Inventory.Interface;assembly=Inventory"
                >
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="date" ObjectType="{x:Type src:DateTime}"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type man:MyListView}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFDFDFE2"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#faf2f2"/>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: A few clear words to explain your solution would benefit users with the same problem. Also, please accept this answer as correct when you can.